# Cannot install melpa packages requiring org

Tags: emacs

My `package.el` configuration looks like this:

```lisp
(defvar gnu '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(defvar melpa '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(defvar org-elpa '("org-elpa" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/"))


(add-to-list 'package-archives gnu t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives melpa t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives org-elpa t)

(defvar el/installed-packages
  (list
   (list 'org org-elpa)
   (list 'org-plus-contrib org-elpa)
   (list 'orgbox melpa)
  )
"List of packages to be installed")

(package-initialize)

(unless (and (file-exists-p "~/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/gnu")
             (file-exists-p "~/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/org-elpa")
             (file-exists-p "~/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/melpa"))
  (package-refresh-contents))

(defun el/packages-install (packages)
  (mapc (lambda (pkg)
          (let ((name (nth 0 pkg))
                (repo (nth 1 pkg)))
            (when (not (package-installed-p name))
              (message "Downloading '%s' ..." name)
              (let ((package-archives (list repo)))
                (package-initialize)
                (package-install name)))))
        packages)
  (package-initialize)
  (delete-other-windows))

(condition-case nil
    (el/packages-install elinstalled-packages)
  (error
   (package-refresh-contents)
   (el/packages-install el/installed-packages)))
```

Naturally there are many more packages listed in `el/installed-packages`.

Upon startup emacs will complain that

> error: Package `org-8.0' is unavailable

which is listed as a dependency of the `orgbox` package. However, the value of `org-version` is `8.2.7c`, therefore installation should not fail!

What further puzzles me is that the `~/.emacs.d/elpa` subdirectory does not contain an `org-$VERSION$` subfolder although the `org-plus-contrib-$VERSION$` folder is present. It appears that `package.el` does not install the `org` package from the `org-elpa` archive, only the `org-plus-contrib` package is installed. Maybe the problem with `orgbox` is related to this?

Answer (score 5):

Org is a built-in package, and thus **always installed** in Emacs.  Consequently, `(package-installed-p 'org)` **always returns a non-nil value**, which prevents Org 8 from being installed by `el/packages-install`.

As of Emacs 24.3, the built-in Org is 7.x, which is not recent enough to match the requirements of `orgbox`.  Normally, package.el would be smart enough to automatically install the required Org 8.x, but since you hide the GNU ELPA archive while installing `orgbox`, package.el fails to resolve the dependency, resulting in the error you have seen.

`org-version` comes from `org-plus-contrib`, which—as the name indicates—also contains all of  Org Mode, thus Org Mode 8 is actually present in your Emacs.  However, since the package name is different (`org-plus-contrib` versus `org`), it can't be used to resolve dependencies against the `org` package.

That's arguably a short-coming of package.el which does not support “virtual” and “provided” packages, but also a result of the messy Org Mode packaging.

To resolve this issue, you could change `el/package-install` to check the installed version of Org by inspecting `package-alist`, but I'd rather recommend you to not mess with `package-archives` in that function.  Notably, you should *not* remove GNU ELPA from that list, since it contains essential packages that must be available for most packages to install cleanly.  You are asking for trouble with this function.

In Emacs 24.3, there is simply **no reasonable way** to pin packages to specific archives.  If you'd like to do that, please update to the latest pretest of Emacs 24.4, and set `package-pinned-archives` accordingly.  If you do so, you don't even need to install Org, since Emacs 24.4 already contains Org 8.

Comment: To solve the immediate problem with `orgbox` I have changed the `el/packages-install` function. Instead of clearing out the `package-archives` list I opted to insert the current repo at the beginning. I have also reordered the default `package-archives` list such that it follows my expected priority scheme. It's not a perfect solution since dependent packages will be [preferably] loaded from the archive of the depending package but this should not matter most of the time. I will upgrade to `emacs 24.4` as soon as I upgrade my whole system, until then I'm stuck with this workaround.

Comment: Could you check [the code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/e5mvZ39t) and give me a review whether you see any problem with this solution?

Comment: @elemakil The order of `package-archives` does not matter.  package.el always takes the highest version from all archives, regardless of their order in `package-archives`.  Your solution does not work as you might expect.

Comment: That is not correct. You can find the test code and output [here](http://pastebin.com/9UnejqVQ).

Comment: @elemakil That output does not contradict my point, since Org has the *same* version in both archives.  Try that with a package that has different versions, e.g. `undo-tree`, which is in MELPA and GNU ELPA.  You'll find that regardless of the order of `package-archives`, you'll *always* get the version from MELPA.

Comment: Hmm... okay, I did not consider that. In my current setup this does not matter since I'm okay with using the newest version, however I've been thinking about taking from packages from `melpa-stable` and I expect those version numbers to be less than the one on `melpa`. So upgrading emacs it is ;-).